# creating marquee style animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I think this should be pretty simple for those jQuery/javascript writers out there. I have a row of divs. I want them to "light-up" one after another, like an old movie marquee. I started thinking about adding and removing classes with `.animate.removeClass` but I wasn't sure how to cycle through the divs. I figure I'd use either a `for` loop or a simple conditional `if (class=on).next.addClass("on").previous.removeClass("off")` Can you tell I don't know javascript syntax?

I do know the basics of CSS animation keyframes, so I went ahead and created a prototype. It's ugly, it's heavy, but it displays the idea:

```
#wrap{
    width: 220px;
}
.dot
{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    background : black;
}
#one{
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-animation:one 4s infinite; 
    animation:one 4s;
}
#two{
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-animation:two 4s infinite;  
}
#three{
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-animation:three 4s infinite;    
}
#four{
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-animation:four 4s infinite;     
}
@-webkit-keyframes one{
    0% {background:black;}
    6% {background:black;}
    8% {background: red;}
    13% {background : black;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes two{
    0% {background:black;}
    10% {background:black;}
    12% {background: red;}
    16% {background : black;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes three{
    0% {background:black;}
    14% {background:black;}
    16% {background: red;}
    20% {background : black;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes four{
    0% {background:black;}
    18% {background:black;}
    20% {background: red;}
    24% {background : black;}
}
```

and the divs, you can see where I started thinking about `addClass`

```
<div id="one" class="dot off"></div>
<div id="two"class="dot off"></div>
<div id="three"class="dot off on"></div>
<div id="four"class="dot off"></div>
```

Comment: No need, just define one animation then stagger the `animation-delay` for each div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the truth, I like the CSS3 solutions more than JavaScript one; but unfortunately most of users still use outdated browsers and you want to have compatibility on most browser versions. So I did something like this for you ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NddCx/)) and I hope this is what you want:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="one" class="dot off"></div>
    <div id="two" class="dot off"></div>
    <div id="three" class="dot off on"></div>
    <div id="four" class="dot off"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrap {
    width: 220px;
}
.dot {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    background : black;
}
.dot.on { background: red !important }
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var $wrap = $("#wrap"); // Caching the wrapper element
    // This function will check to see if we have any element 
    // with .on class inside wrapper. If not, the first .dot will get an .on class.
    // If there is any .dot with .on class we will find the next sibling to it
    // and then remove .on class from former element and add .on to next item.
    function goNext() {
        if ($wrap.find(".dot.on").length) { // if we have any .on
            var $on = $wrap.find(".dot.on"); // Caching current .on element
            var $next = $wrap.find(".dot.on").next(); // Finding next item
            $on.removeClass('on'); // removing .on class from current active item
            if ($next.length) { // If there are any next sibling
                $next.addClass('on'); // Next item gets an .on class
            } else { // if current item is the last one
                goNext(); // Call current function again and give first item .on class
            }
        } else { // If we don't have any .on item
            $wrap.find(".dot:first").addClass('on'); // give .on class to first .dot
        }
    }
    // Creating a timer to call the function every 0.5 seconds
    setInterval(function(){ goNext () }, 500);
});
```

Comment: thanks faridv, can you explain why you use the `.length` property? it seems to be just returning "there is a length" to the conditional. these are the basic coding tricks(skills) I struggle with.

Comment: @icicleking you're welcome. `.length` is a javascript property which returns number of nodelist. for example if you have 4 items with `.dot` class, using `$(".dot").length` will return 4. I used it in my code to check if there are any `.dot.on` inside the wrapper, and later to check if there are any next items. Use [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.length) for more description. And if you found my answer helping, please mark it as accepted answer.